# How to pass behavior to Akka actor

Tags: scala, akka

I'm building Akka app which will retrieve RSS feeds (XML) from several sites. For each site I will create some class which will transform XML to some generalized object (Scala case class) with common fields from all RSS feeds:

```
case class RssFeed(title: String, ...)

trait RssTransformer {
  def getRssFeed(): Seq[RssFeed]
}

class FooTransformer(...) extends RssTransformer  {
   override def getRssFeed(): : Seq[RssFeed] = {...}
} 

class BarTransformer(...) extends RssTransformer  {
   override def getRssFeed(): : Seq[RssFeed] = {...}
}
```

And I want create Akka actors and pass to each of them some implementation of transformer (for example one actor will work with `BarTransformer`, another with `FooTransformer` etc).

The problem is that I'm using DI framework (Spring) to initiate actors, *so I can't pass transformers through actor`s constructor parameters*. The only way is to pass it using some Message, but passing behavior in messages is anti-pattern in Akka.

Can you please advice me how I can solve this problem, or even better if you can give me some adviсe on how to improve app architecture to avoid this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of logic goes into the decision of which transformer to use? Is the logic based on the message type or payload?

Comment: @nattyddubbs, no, it will not be determined in runtime, but at compile time. I.e. I'm just need to retrieve data from different sites in same time (once per day, for example). So, I will manually create 5-6 actors at compile time and provide to each of them some implementation of transformer. I'm just want to generalize actor's code, and pass to it encapsulated behavior for retrieving and transforming data. I.e. `BarTransformer` will make HTTP request to some site, retrieve XML, transform it to `Seq[RssFeed]` and return. So my actors will work with `RssTransformer` regardless of implementation

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure why you say `using DI framework ... so I can't pass transformers through an actor's constructor parameters.` It seems like that's exactly what you would want the DI framework to do. See here: http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2015/05/akka-samples-with-scala-and-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "so I can't pass transformers through actor's constructor parameters." With spring you can use the `constructor-arg` element to provide [constructor arguments](http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-multiple-parameter-constructor-injection.html).

If the problem is you must create Actors using the `ActorSystem#actorOf` method, one solution would be to define your own [Factory Bean](http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-factory-bean.html) that takes an `ActorSystem` and some `Props` as constructor arguments and constructs your Actor.